# ¿Cómo hacer una condición para que solo se concatene un solo registro de muchos que son iguales?

Tags: python

Deseo concatenar solo un registro en caso de que existan muchos con el mismo registro, es decir si hay 5 lapiceros registrados, se muestran los 5 registros pero yo solo quiero concatenar un registro, no sé si me explico

```py
diario=''
busines = self.env['account.move.line'].search([('move_id','=',linea[12])])
if busines:
   for y in busines:
      if y.product_id.as_bussiness_id:
         diario+=y.product_id.as_bussiness_id.name + ', '
```

Comment: Creo d+que deberías de añadir el resto del código y seguro que así te explicas mucho mejor

Comment: Quizás los conjuntos [set](https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) puedan serte de utilidad.

Answer (score 0):

No trabajes con strings para este tipo de operaciones. Utiliza listas o sets.

Si utilizas listas tendrás que comprobar que el elemento a añadir no está actualmente presente:

```
diario = []
busines = self.env['account.move.line'].search([('move_id','=',linea[12])])
if busines:
    for y in busines:
        if y.product_id.as_bussiness_id and y.product_id.as_bussiness_id.name not in diario:
            diario+=y.product_id.as_bussiness_id.name

diario = ', '.join(diario)
```

Si utilizas un set puedes operar de la siguiente manera:

```
busines = self.env['account.move.line'].search([('move_id','=',linea[12])])
diario = ', '.join(set([x for x in busines if x.product_id.as_bussiness_id]))
```

Ten en cuenta que un set es una estructura de datos sin orden.

Comment: En la propuesta con set, puedes, en lugar de crear una lista y convertirla en un set, puedes directamente crear el set `{x for x in busines if x.product_id.as_bussiness_id}`

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo. Me emperré en que el OP viese que lo que quiere hacer no tiene sentido hacerlo con strings.